# How long to see results in citrus tree after soil remediation?

Tags: fertilizer, citrus, phosphorous, grapefruit

I recently discovered that a nutrient imbalance might be contributing to a grapefruit tree having fruit with thick rinds and no fruit/pulp. [Here's the explanation I'm working from.](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/fruits/citrus/citrus-fruit-thick-rind.htm#:%7E:text=The%20thick%20rind%20is%20caused,thus%20causing%20a%20phosphorus%20deficiency.&text=Phosphorus%20helps%20the%20plant%20to%20form%20flowers%20and%20fruit.) If I add bone meal to the soil, I'm wondering how long I might expect to wait until seeing better results in the fruit. And is there ideal timing to add the bone meal in this scenario, or is it best to just add it as soon as possible?

Comment: Looking at you reference ; I think it shows a pomelo fruit, a Chinese grapefruit .  I bought one at a market in China where no one spoke English.  The peel was exceptionally thick and fruit sour . I have only seen them once in the US. But websites offer trees for sale. If it is a pomelo , phosphorus won't help. It depends where you got the tree.  Be interesting to hear what happens next year.

Comment: Phosphorous is not mobile in the soil unlike nitrogen so you would be better off with a foliar spray and adding compost around the tree

Comment: Thanks for the responses here. The fruits on the tree in question are 100% peel, with no fruit at all. @blacksmith37  - can you expand any more on why phosphorus won't help for pomelos?

Comment: Although they look like grapefruit on the outside , pomelos are a different fruit with a very thick peel . So fertilizer will not influence their growth much. It sounds like you have one ; you would need to replace the tree.